# Nautilus freezes if mounted SSHFS-Device is unreachable

Tags: nautilus, sshfs

Using SSHFS to mount remote file systems in the user space, I have the problem that all instances of Nautilus use to freeze, if one of the mounted hosts is unreachable. That problem occurs with Nautilus 2.X and 3.X and I cant find any solution until today. This problem makes SSHFS almost unusable, at least using an unstable WLAN or something like it. Is this a Nautilus bug? Can anyone confirm this problem, is there a solution?

Answer (score 4):

This is [Bug 657208](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=657208) in GNOME Bugzilla.

**Update:**

Also there is a possible workaround found in [SSHFS FAQ](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=SshfsFaq#sshfs_hangs_after_a_while):

> **sshfs hangs after a while**
>
> Mounting works fine, I can use the files in Mountpoint as good as any
>   other files on my system, but after bit of time, changing nothing on
>   the remote files sshfs crashes. This means, I can not cd into the
>   Mountpoint (xterm hangs, *nautilus hangs*... every program trying to
>   access the Mountpoint gets stuck, and won't return).
>
> *Solution:* add
>
> `ServerAliveInterval 15`
>
> in your `.ssh/config` (or use `-o ServerAliveInterval=15` on the sshfs
>   command line but I did not test that solution). This will force the
>   ssh connection to stay alive even if you have no activity.

Comment: More thorough answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/716612/sshfs-auto-reconnect/716618#716618. In short, use: `sshfs -o reconnect,ServerAliveInterval=15,ServerAliveCountMax=3 server:/path/to/mount`

Answer (score 1):

More thorough answer here: [SSHFS - auto reconnect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/716612/sshfs-auto-reconnect/716618#716618).

In short, use:

```
sshfs -o reconnect,ServerAliveInterval=15,ServerAliveCountMax=3 server:/path/to/mount
```