# SSHFS - auto reconnect

Tags: 14.04, server, sshfs

I have an SSHFS mount that I can connect using the command line:

```
echo myPassword | sudo sshfs user@home.address:/ /media/NAS -p31337 -o workaround=rename -o password_stdin -o allow_other
```

which seems to mount my NAS to `/media/NAS` well enough.

Very occasionally the connection will be broken if there's a power or Internet outtage, and in these cases I would have to recognise this has happened and manually reconnect using the same command.

Is there a way I can get my Ubuntu Server to automatically attempt to reconnect, say every 30 seconds, if the connection goes down?

Thanks.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This question is answered on https://serverfault.com/questions/6709/sshfs-mount-that-survives-disconnect/639735. I am duplicating it here.

```
sshfs -o reconnect,ServerAliveInterval=15,ServerAliveCountMax=3 server:/path/to/mount
```

As explained at the Server Fault link, the `ServerAliveInterval=15` option asked `sshfs` to check if the server is alive every 15 seconds. `ServerAliveCountMax=3` allows the server to not respond for up to three alive checks. The result is that if the server is unavailable for 1 minute, `sshfs` will reconnect to the server.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification - I thought ServerAliveInterval and ServerAliveCountMax defined how long the client would retry before giving up.